# Serialize form não pega a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esta função para verificar se algo foi alterado no `formulário`, aparentemente ela funcionava perfeitamente:

```
    $(function () {
    var init_form = $('#editarproduto').serialize();
    $(':submit').click(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; }); window.onbeforeunload = function () { var check_form = $('#editarproduto').serialize(); console.log(check_form); console.log(init_form); if (check_form === init_form) return null; return 'Os dados do formulário não foram salvos, deseja permanecer nesta página?'; };
});
```

Porém surgiu a necessidade dele verifica a `table`, se algo foi escondido nela, ele não pega as alterações nesta `table`:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" id="tabelaf" name="tabelaf">
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model.ProdutosFornecedores)
                                {
                                <tr class="tr item">
                                    <td>@item.FornecedorProduto.Id</td>
                                    <td>@item.FornecedorProduto.Nome</td>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <a class="link-excluir" href="#" data-id="@item.Id" title="Excluir"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></a>&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Como fazer para que ele compare esta `table` também ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>O método serialize do JQuery só serializa valores de elementos com nome (e que não estão desabilitados), se você quiser comparar os dados da table usando serialize, você deve dar um nome a todos os elementos, e também um valor (o qual provavelmente será o mesmo que o HTML interno).</s>

**Exemplo**:

```
<td name="id[]" value="@item.FornecedorProduto.Id">@item.FornecedorProduto.Id</td>
<td name="nome[]" value="@item.FornecedorProduto.Nome">@item.FornecedorProduto.Nome</td>
```

**Edit: CORREÇÃO**
JQuery só serializa valores de elementos do tipo input, textarea ou select, então mesmo com um nome os valores do td não serão serializados. No caso seria necessário um input do tipo hidden com os mesmos valores da td.

Comment: eu fiz exatamente isso, coloquei do tipo hidden e deu certo,